# How to make WiX Toolset (Burn) Bootstrapper recognize an upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I'm using the WiX (Burn) Bootstrapper to wrap my MSI installer (so that I can install some prerequisite libraries with it.)

It works fine for installation and uninstallation, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement an upgrade with it? Say, if I had version 1.0.0 installed and now I run it for version 1.0.1.

PS. I made sure that `UpgradeCode` values in the XML markup for both MSI and bootstrapper are the same. But it didn't help. The bootstrapper still behaves like an upgrade to the next version is just a plain installation.

Answer (score 2):

The upgraded bootstrapper should behave like a plain installation. If version 1.0.1 was installed successfully, everything is ok.

If you want bootstrapper to detect previous version, you should use custom bootstrapper application and DetectRelatedBundle event.